# How add a listener to remove a function in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to 'listen' the remove envent in a MongoDB schema named *Post*. Once the user removes one post, that haves one image on AmazonWeb Cloud, I have to remove this image from the cloud. My problem is that this listener doesn't work, maybe it's outdated; I need some alternative to this code.

Here the code of the schema (**PostSchema**):

```js
//imports
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promissify } = require('util');

//using AWS's lib
const s3 = new aws.S3();

//Schema declaration
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    size: Number,
    key: String,
    url: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

//listener to all 'save' events (it works)
PostSchema.pre('save', function() {
    if(!this.url) {
        this.url = `${process.env.APP_URL}/files/${this.key}`
    }
});

//LISTENER THAT NOT WORKS
PostSchema.pre('remove', function() {
    //if the storage type defined is AWS, delete image from AWS
    //else, delete from local storage
    if(process.env.STORAGE_TYPE == 's3') {
        return s3.
            deleteObject({
                Bucket: 'upload-example-nodeapp',
                Key: this.key
            })
            .promise()
    } else {
        return promissify(fs.unlink)(
            path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp', 'uploads', this.key)
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something like `Model.remove` to remove the document you have to use the `{ query:true }` option

```
schema.pre('remove', { query: true }, function() {
  console.log('Removing!');
});
```

by default it uses the `{ document: true }` option ant the hook only fires when you use `doc.remove`. This is all writen in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: In my case, when I put `{ query: true }` the key attribute on `this` desappear. It happens because with the query attribute is true, `this` is a query reference and not a document reference. I just put `{ query: false, document: true }` and it works. Thanks!